# How can I make my images consume less memory?

Tags: android

I am developing a game and I was working with the graphics, I run into some force closes. So my question is : **How can we make images to consume less memory in android?**

I´ll explain my game, it´s a logic game with a few small images and a background. I´m testing the app in a galaxy note, 1 GB of RAM, and I thought it could take the high resolution but if I use big image for the background, it force closes after going to the pause layout and back.

So I have lowered the graphics and done with no force closes. Anyway is there some way to avoid this memory issue? I´m setting the images directly on the xml is that wrong?

---

#### Solved

I have decided to go with this method, thanks to Durairaj Packirisamy for the answer

Here is my code:

```
        Bitmap unscaledimgswitch = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.switch1on);
    ImageView switch1 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.switch1);
    
    
    int viewheight =  screenheight / 10;
    int imgheight = unscaledimgswitch.getHeight();
    switch1.getLayoutParams().height = viewheight;


    

    BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
    options.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
    options.inSampleSize = ScaledFactor.getScaleFactor(imgheight ,viewheight); // de esta forma cargo la imagen del tamaño exacto necesario
    options.inJustDecodeBounds = false; 
    imgswitch = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.switch1on, options);
    switch1.setImageBitmap(imgswitch);
```

And in an other class

```
    static int getScaleFactor(int imgheight, int viewheight) { 
    int result;
    
result = imgheight / viewheight ;
    
    

    return result;
}
```

Comment: As high as the resolution is I think you should only include image with size you need, for each ldpi, mdpi, hdpi and xhdpi, or higher densities. Eg, you do not need a 1600×900 image for 1280x800 galaxy note (xhdpi)

Comment: I know that, but it´s not what I´m asking. :)

Comment: You're asking how to avoid memory issue, not setting an overly large bitmap to unnecessary density is one of the answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use  a proper BitmapFactory.options.inSampleSize value, If set to a value > 1, requests the decoder to subsample the original image, returning a smaller image to save memory.

```
BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
options.inSampleSize = 4;
Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(stream, null, options);
```

Also have a look here:

http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/load-bitmap.html

Comment: so i should  find view of the layout, and setBackgroundImage(bitmap)  ( im not shure that is the code but thats the idea) ? And set the BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.id.myimage, options) ?
doesn´t the mdpi, hdpi ldpi folders on the drawable do the same?

Comment: thanks after some studying I managed to do it your way. Some coding for today but less problems for tomorrow. I really appreciate your answer. I had to change half my code but it works awesome now.